# Unable to inspect this elisp function: en/disable-command

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was interested in how `disable-command` was implemented so I looked it up and its code was just this:

```
(defun disable-command (command)
  "...."
  (interactive "CDisable command: ")
  (en/disable-command command t))
```

Then I wanted see how `en/disable-command` was implemented, so I pressed `M-.` while point was on `en/disable-command` which showed nothing. Then I tried `C-h f en/disable-command` which also failed. Why does this fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the code of an unloaded library.

`disable-command` is autoloaded, so you can use `describe-function` and `find-function` on it, but that doesn't load the library, and Emacs can't tell you about functions which are neither loaded nor autoloaded, as it has no information about them.

Load `novice` (or just `eval-buffer` as you're there already), and you'll be able to find `en/disable-command`.

(I don't know why it's not in your TAGS file, however, but that's presumably down to how you built it.)

Comment: I downloaded GNU Emacs for MS Windows from the official homepage and then extracted it and that's what I am using. Maybe this is why TAGS or something similar is not set up.

Comment: Yes, you can't use `find-tag` if you haven't created a TAGS file.